# iOS Installing Pods query

Tags: ios, cocoapods

i am having ios version 10.13.1 and when i had added ios version 10.0 in my pod file

platform :ios, '10.0'

```
use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myapp

target 'myapp' do   

end
```

or

platform :ios, '10.13.1'

```
 use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myapp

target 'myapp' do   

end
```

so my question is do i need to update ios version as 10.0 to 10.13.1 in podfile or is it fine with ios version:10.0 ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Just to be clear - there is no iOS 10.13.1. The latest update to iOS was 10.3.3.

Comment: but i am talking about macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.1...  and it's available....

Comment: @Losiowaty u can check from below link - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12

Comment: Yet in your question you never mention macOS, only iOS. It is even tagged `iOS` ;)

Comment: ohhh...hahaha.... Thanks buddy my mistake :)  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can specify 10.0. Its the minimum version should be supported

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Comment: and is there any problem if we write as (platform :ios, '10.13.1') ?

Comment: No, there is no problem. If your project's minimum target is 10.13.1. it will work fine